# Can't get the latest version of Ruby to work on my Mac, keeps using old version

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I am unable to use the newest version of Ruby on my Mac, even though I have it installed.

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
  3.1.0
  3.1.2
* 3.2.2 (set by /Users/angelina/.ruby-version)
```

Because of this I also can't use my coco pods. When I check version of ruby it says.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I think it's because my Mac is using whatever is in bin/ruby and not what is in rvm.

I have tried a few things that seem to work

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
$ ruby --version
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-darwin22]
```

but then once the terminal reverts, everything stays the same

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
```

Comment: Sounds like your shell doesn't load rbenv on startup. Run `rbenv init` and follow the instructions.